# Fetch SQL rows with priority

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following tables structure:

***forms***

```
RID | MODULE
------------
1   | indiv
2   | indiv
3   | indiv
```

***translations***

```
RID | LANG | VALUE | MODULE | TAG |
-----------------------------------
1   |   en |car    |        |     |
1   |   en |truck  |indiv   |     |
1   |   en |boat   |indiv   |C100 |
2   |   en |hat    |        |     |
3   |   en |cat    |        |     |
3   |   en |dog    |indiv   |     |
4   |   en |light  |        |     |
5   |   en |dark   |        |     |
```

I need to fetch only one row per `RID` from `translations` table, based on **additional** (but not mandatory) parameters for `module` and `tag` columns, i.e.:

***RESULT without input parameters***:

```
RID | LANG | VALUE | MODULE | TAG |
-----------------------------------
1   |   en |car    |        |     |
2   |   en |hat    |        |     |
3   |   en |cat    |        |     |
```

***RESULT with one input parameter*** `module='indiv'`:

```
RID | LANG | VALUE | MODULE | TAG |
-----------------------------------
1   |   en |truck  |indiv   |     |
2   |   en |hat    |        |     |
3   |   en |dog    |indiv   |     |
```

If I have two input parameters the result to be:

***RESULT with two parameters:*** `module='indiv' AND tag='c100'`

```
RID | LANG | VALUE | MODULE | TAG |
-----------------------------------
1   |   en |boat   |indiv   |C100 |
2   |   en |hat    |        |     |
3   |   en |dog    |indiv   |     |
```

How can I achieve this with SQL only on ORACLE DB server? A query example for the last case with two parameters will be enough for me as previous cases are subsets from last one with `NULL` of these columns I believe. If you think that all these cases are too different and require different SQL statements, you are more than welcome to write them as well.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected behavior if you have `module='error'` or `module='indiv' AND tag='error'` or `module='error' AND tag='c100'`?

Comment: First, SQL statements do not have parameters, only bind variables. And if you want one statement, same set of variables should be bound each time. So "without input parameters" would probably mean some bind variables are set to NULL. That brings me to the question — why in this case you expect these particular rows? Because they have NULLs in `MODULE` and `TAG` or because they are somehow "first"? If the latter is true then you need some key to sort rows. Anyway, you need to rank rows and get first one. The question is which expression should be used for sort.

Comment: When `module='indiv'` why do you choose `truck`  over `boat` (in the value column)

Comment: @MT0, `module='error'` should work as second result example, all other cases should return the result from third example.

Comment: @Magnus, because `boat` is specific translation only for `c100` module and must be taken only when i need it for that module.

Comment: @Thatyoungman, yes I know that, SQL statements will be build dynamically based on input parameters via Java or PHP. Thats why i've mention that there is no problem to use different queries.

Comment: @mitkosoft what if `truck` had tag `C100` also, which row to choose then for `module='indiv'` ?

Comment: @Magnus, in general this case is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT  t.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY RID
            ORDER BY CASE
                     WHEN module = LOWER( :mod ) AND tag = UPPER( :tag ) THEN 1
                     WHEN                            tag = UPPER( :tag ) THEN 2
                     WHEN module = LOWER( :mod ) AND tag IS NULL         THEN 3
                     WHEN module IS NULL         AND tag IS NULL         THEN 4
                                                                         ELSE 5
                     END
        ) AS rn
  FROM  translations t
  WHERE ( module IS NULL OR module = LOWER( :mod ) )
  OR    ( tag IS NULL OR tag = UPPER( :tag ) )

)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I don't see any JOIN of `forms` table, so as result I've receive unnecessary rows from translations table, no matter do I have assigned `:mod` value or not.

Comment: That is because the `FORMS` table is mentioned in passing but there is no obvious requirement, stated in your question, for a join as you can get your expected results without using it. If you require a join then add it but we don't have enough information to know what the join parameters should be (although I could guess at `INNER JOIN forms f ON ( f.RID = t.RID AND ( t.module = f.module OR t.module IS NULL ) )` but this is only a guess)

Comment: MT0, Actually RID is the JOIN condition as in my result examples I do not include the rows with ID 4 and 5 from translations table.

Comment: You should be able to add that easily enough to my query - as I said, the use of the `forms` table is unclear from the question and the RID 4 & 5 rows appeared in your edit with no explanation as to why they were relevant or why they should be excluded from the output. Please edit your question to make the requirements clear.

Comment: Yes, with small modifications this works more than well, thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT F.RID,
         T.LANG,
         T.VALUE,
         T.MODULE,
         T.TAG,
         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY F.RID
                     ORDER BY DECODE(T.MODULE, :module, 1, 2),
                              DECODE(T.TAG,    :tag,    1, 2))   RANK
  FROM   forms F INNER JOIN translations T
    ON T.RID = F.RID)
WHERE RANK = 1
```

So you rank rows with `MODULE = :module` or/and `TAG = :tag` higher. You still need something to do with ties, but you get the idea. `RANK` leaves ties, `ROW_NUMBER` does not.

I put `MODULE` higher than `TAG` because of your examples. You might need to change it if you can input tags without modules.

And also, `DECODE` maps NULL to NULL, so if `:module` is not set, you will get match with rows having NULL in `MODULE`.

Comment: Thanks, but this query is very slow and I've receive following ORA error after while: `ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 256 in tablespace TEMP`

Comment: I do not see any immediate reason for this query to be slow and consume lots of space in `TEMP`. I would need more info about your tables, amount of data stored and indexes created.